# How do I access parameters I assigned to URL with branch.io?

Tags: ios, swift, branch.io

I simply create an URL like this:

```
Branch.getInstance().getShortURL(withParams: ["a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["c": 34, "d": "Malwina is OK:-)"]]) { url, error in

    let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [URL(string: url!)!], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And I get something like this:

```
https://fieldserviceios.app.link/Hjp9gesGIB
```

And from that link I try to open the app and catch that parameters:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

    let a = Branch.getInstance().getLatestReferringParams() //no my params here
}
```

Comment: Great! Is there a problem? If so, it would be helpful to get a description of the issue and to see the console output when you test with setDebug enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are creating the link is fine and you are generating a valid link. You can check the contents of any Branch link by appending "?debug=true" to the link and entering it in a browser's address bar.

For your link: https://fieldserviceios.app.link/Hjp9gesGIB?debug=true I see:

```
{ 
    "$identity_id": "372863071192286427", 
    "$one_time_use": false, 
    "a": [1,2,3], 
    "b": { 
        "c": 34, 
        "d": "Malwina jest OK:-)" 
    }, 
    "~creation_source": 3, 
    "~id": "373038618178427139" 
}
```

I describe how you should go about reading the parameters from the link in my response to your other Stack Overflow question, here: [How do I access metadata when branch link was clicked and opened my app...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955474/how-do-i-access-metadata-when-branch-link-was-clicked-and-opened-my-app), but speaking to the specific code you provide:

- Your continueUserActivity function should not have a getLatestReferringParams call but should have:

  Branch.getInstance().continue(userActivity)
- You need to initialize Branch in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, using branch.initSession. For an example, see: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/Branch-TestBed-Swift/TestBed-Swift/AppDelegate.swift#L43-L74